# CSS Media Query Landscape - Keyboard Issue

Tags: android, ios, css, media-queries

I tried in my mobile page

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
  /* My landscape based CSS here */
}
```

It's broken on keyboard opened.

After I tried;

```
@media only screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) {
/* Landscape */
}
```

Tested and works on;

Nexus 5,
iPhone 4,
 
iPhone 6,
iPhone 6+, 
Samsung Note 4,
Samsung S3,
Samsung S4,
Samsung S5, 
but it is still broken on when keyboard opened on 
`Nexus 4`.

I couldn't find any global solution with CSS. Any help will be much appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I didn't came up with and straight answer but hacked out Nexus 4.

```
@media only screen and (width: 384px) and (height:233px) {
    /*my landscape div sets out display:none on nexus 4*/
}
```